# Negative grounding times in nycflights13 dataset

Tags: r

I am new to R and I was trying to analyze the nycflights13 dataset. I was curious about the air_time variable in the dataset and how it was related to the time difference between the arrival and departure times for a flight. I wrote the following code block to calculate grounding_time as the proportion of time an airplane spends on the ground (taxiing, etc.).

```
flight_data <- flights |>
  mutate(dep_time_act = dep_time - tz_origin * 100,
         arr_time_act = arr_time - tz_dest * 100,
         dep_time_min = dep_time_act %% 100,
         arr_time_min = arr_time_act %% 100,
         dep_time_hours = as.integer(dep_time_act / 100),
         arr_time_hours = as.integer(arr_time_act / 100),
         arr_time_hours = ifelse(arr_time_min < dep_time_min,
                                 arr_time_hours - 1, arr_time_hours),
         arr_time_min = ifelse(arr_time_min < dep_time_min, arr_time_min + 60,
                               arr_time_min),
         overnight = ifelse(arr_time_act < dep_time_act, 1, 0),
         arr_time_hours = arr_time_hours + overnight * 24,
         time_taken_min = (arr_time_hours - dep_time_hours) * 60 +
           (arr_time_min - dep_time_min),
         grounding_time = time_taken_min - air_time,
         grounding_prop = round(grounding_time / time_taken_min * 100, 2)) |>
  relocate(dep_time_min, .after = dep_time) |>
  relocate(arr_time_min, .after = arr_time) |>
  relocate(dep_time_hours, .after = dep_time_min) |>
  relocate(arr_time_hours, .after = arr_time_min) |>
  relocate(time_taken_min, .after = air_time) |>
  select(-ends_with("_act"))
```

However, when I ordered the resulting dataset by grounding_time, some of the flights have negative times.

[Flight data for negative grounding times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x78pX.png)

I have accounted for the time zones by merging the airports dataset for respective offsets. I have also calculated the difference between the adjusted time for minutes and hours separately. I have also used the overnight parameter to consider overnight flights with earlier arrival times than departure after time zone adjustment.

In my understanding, the adjusted time difference between arrival and departure, should be less than the time spent in air for any flight.

I would really appreciate any help in understanding the reasons for this anomaly, and any suggestions to tackle this.